# Interleaving user code with library code in Project Reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am working on a library that returns to users a `Flux<Message>`. After they perform some operations on that `Message`, I have to perform an asynchronous operation to acknowledge it on the server-side. Is it possible to interleave user code and library code?

In my current implementation, I created a `FluxProcessor<Message, Message>`, but when I call `service.complete(message).block()`, it throws an `IllegalStateException` "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread single-1".

We have to schedule our server-side operations on the single scheduler, so I understand why it is throwing.

Are there any operators I could use? Any suggestions would be helpful!

```java
// This is the public facing API that the users would interact with.
public class Receiver {
    public Flux<Message> receive() {
        return streamMessagesFromService().subscribeWith(new MessageProcessor());
    }
}

class MessageProcessor extends FluxProcessor<Message, Message> implements Subscription {
    // This is the server-side complete operation.
    private final Function<Message, Mono<Void>> completeFunction;

    private volatile CoreSubscriber<? super Message> downstream;

    @Override
    public void onNext(Message message) {
        // Let the user do whatever with that message downstream.
        downstream.onNext(message);

        // This is where it throws the IllegalStateException.
        completeFunction.apply(message).block();
    }
}
```

Comment: I could be missing something here, but could you not do without the processor entirely and then call something like `return streamMessagesFromService().flatMap(m -> completeFunction.apply(m).thenReturn(m));` in `receive()`?

Comment: An external customer would chain something after `receive()`, like `receive().subscribe(e -> { System.out.println("Message:" +  message); });` in addition to some other processing. After they do their own message processing, I our library to call that server-side complete fuction. 

Does that make it a bit more clear?

Comment: Ah, I see, so you need the `completeFunction` to complete only *after* any subscription from the user?